# Regex for file, specially pdf - Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new at creating regulars expressions, but I am not sure how to do it to validate the creation of the name of a pdf file (created by myself). I don't want any special character or spaces, etc. I want to do it with Javascript, I don't know if that is important. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: ***"I don't want any special character or spaces, etc"*** - you need to be way more specific than this.

Comment: And what have you tried so far!? *I don't know if that is important*

Comment: To add to @PedroLobito's comment... What is "special" to you? If you mean that you do not want _invalid_ file characters, that depends on the operating system you are on (Windows is different than MacOS, for example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming some common practices about file names, I would suggest one restricts a filename to alphanumeric-characters, slash, underscore and some brackets, then generally I would use the following piece of code

```
var patt =/^[a-z0-9_()\-\[\]]+\.pdf$/i;
var fileName = "my_test.pdf";
if (fileName.search(patt) < 0) {
  // filename doesn't match the Regex
} else {
  // filename matches the Regex
}
```

Generally the JS regex has two parts in this case, */regex/i* where regex is the regex (doh), and *i* is a switch meaning "ignore-case". The regex itself says that anything from **a-z, 0-9, underscore, parenthesis, (escaped) slash, (escaped) opening and closing square brackets**, should be allowed at least one time (*the + sign*), and this should be followed by a (escaped) dot and the "pdf" string.

The **^** sign stands for "beginning of string" and the **$** stands for "end of string". So this will help you avoid situation like this:

```
%`some_valid_name.pdf``*\
```

If you do not put the **^** and **$** signs, this will be a valid match, according to regex.

Comment: Thank you. But I have a few questions. 1- Why do you put a $ symbol after pdf? 2 - What does it mean the ^ symbol after slash? 3 - What is doh?

Comment: Yes, sorry, forgot to put those in. Changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was what I looking for.